# SoapUI Rest Call JSON : Reading Body of request from file or attachment

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

Is there any way to add body of request from file or attachment to JSON call?
I tried attachments but to no avail. From file I'm not sure. I know I could construct body using groovy script but that would be time consuming thing for so much diff calls I have.

2nd Question if this is possible then would parameters read in such a manner be actually expanded?
Example of body read/sent:

```
{
  "data": [ {"id": "zz","integerValue":"${GLOBAL_SOAPUI_PARAMETER}"} ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly can't you just use a datasource and then insert the body via a property? For example

```
"data": [ {"id": "zz","integerValue":"${DataSource#body}"}]
```

Comment: Sorry If I confused you.No ,I want the Whole Body to be read either from file or attachment,not just one or more of the properties.Is this possible even ?

Comment: Does this help? http://thetestsuite.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/overhaul-test-automation-with-soapui-using-jsonbuilder-and-jsonslurper/